# Equivalence concept of integration.

Tags: measure-theory

> A measurable function $f$ is integrable over a measurable set $E$ of finite measure if and only if the series
>   $$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E\cap \{x:|f(x)|\geq n\})$$
>   converges.

I could solve the only if part: suppose that $f$ is integrable then the inequality

$$\sum_{n=1}^k\chi_{\{x:|f(x)|\geq n\}}\leq |f| \chi_{\{x:|f(x)|\geq k\}}$$

and the use of Lebesgue Dominated theorem, we conclude that

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(E\cap \{x:|f(x)|\geq n\})$$

converges.

But I don't know how to prove the other side. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  $$|f| \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \chi_{\{x; |f(x)| \geq k\}}.$$